# Problem: LG Optimus One P500 powering off after 2.3 (gingerbread) update

Tags: android, lg

I've updated my P500 to 2.3.3 (Gingerbread) using LGMobile Support Tool, as described at http://www.lge.com/br/android/p500/atualizacao/index.jsp (pt_BR). Now, a couple of hours after running it gets powered off and won't turn on without taking the battery off and putting it back. Then, battery is about 60-80% charged (not drained).

I called LG support and they told me to hard reset the phone (home + vol. down + power) and reinstall. I did it, but the problem persists. Any suggestion to resolve this? If not, is it possible to downgrade to 2.2 (Froyo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it flashing back LG's ROM for Android 2.2.1 (V10a), using KDZ Updater. Followed this tutorial (pt_BR): http://p500brasil.blogspot.com/2011/06/reinstalando-firmware-original-no-lg.html.